# Moving to the next row of a search array during a loop, but breaking when a column changes

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I am working on looping through a MySQL table of data and building an HTML table (in php) that will display names in this table while a specific column or columns stay the same. Once these columns change, then I need to break out of the internal loop, and iterate to the next row of the SQL table and then start the internal loop again while the columns remain the same.

```
 JobId  |        email        |  FName  |  LName  |  apply
   1    |   email1@gmail.com  |   Joe   |  Smith  |   1
   1    |   email1@gmail.com  |   Kim   | Joseph  |   1
   1    |   email1@gmail.com  |  Chris  |   Bell  |   1
   2    |   email2@gmail.com  |   Ben   |   Ken   |   0
   2    |   email2@gmail.com  |   Sam   |  Socks  |   1
   3    |   email3@gmail.com  |   Tom   |  Allen  |   0
```

Given the table above, what I want to do is be able to send 1 e-mail to email1@gmail.com with Joe, Kim, and Chris' name in it. Then iterate down and send a second e-mail to email2@gmail.com with Ben and Sam's name in the message, and then a third email to email3@gmail.com with Tom's name in the message body.

I have already written the code of how to send emails and such. What I am having trouble with is iterating through the query correctly. So I have echoed the results onto a webpage to help me work through it so i'm not sending 1000s of emails. Here is my work thus far:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo 'Applicants: <br />';
        $JobId = $row['JobId'];
    echo $row['FName'] . ' ' . $row['LNname'] . '<br />';
    while (mysqli_fetch_array($result)['JobId'] == $JobId){
        echo $row['FName'] . ' ' . $row['LName'] . '<br />';
    }
    echo 'email address: ' . $row['email'] . '<br /><br />';
}
```

This iterates through and gives me the correct e-mail address only once which is great. However, it gives me the same FName and LName each time it iterates. Which I know why (the $row array is not iterated to the next row in the query). So that is the piece I'm missing how to do.

I also think that the number of times it displays names is incorrect...not as important, but if you instantly see why, that would be great help as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work: you just need to check whether the current `JobId` is different from the previous, and also keep a record (here in a temporary variable `$email`) of the most recent email address. Warning: I haven't tested this!

```
$JobId = 0;
echo 'Applicants: <br />';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($row['JobId'] == $JobId) {
        // Nothing changed so save the email & carry on printing out names.
        $email = $row['email'];
        echo $row['FName'] . ' ' . $row['LNname'] . '<br />';
    } else {
        // We have a new JobId, so send the email, set the JobId marker,
        // and print the "Applicants" header again.
        echo 'Sending email to '.$email;
        $JobId = $row['JobId'];
        echo 'Applicants: <br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about giving this single loop solution, which requires less memory, but opted to give option that would perhaps be more understandable to OP.  Personally, I would take this approach though as it would be better from a performance and memory utilization perspective.  +1

Comment: @GluePear I marked your answer as correct because it got me close enough and I was able to figure out the pieces that weren't quite working right after testing. I have included an answer in a response below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You nested while loops make no sense here since there is only a single result set you are looping through.  If memory usage is not a major concern, I would suggest building a multi-dimensional array to work with to simplify things, with email being the first dimension.  Something like this:

```
// build array
$email_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $email_array[$row['email']][] = $row;
}

// loop array
foreach($email_array as $email => $row) {
    // $email contains the target email address
    // $row contains array holding JobId, FName, Lname, apply
    // build your email here with some logic
    // send your email to $email
    // iterate loop to get to next email address
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@GluePear gave me some great info and I was able to test it and then troubleshoot the rest. GluePear's code gave me mostly what I wanted, but it was missing the first name of each grouping for some reason. So I did some work and realized that it was because when it got to the else statement, the array was already on the next row, but we weren't printing a name. so I just added an echo with the name of the applicant there and also an initializing If statement and voila! Below is the code.

```
$first = 1;
echo 'Applicants: <br />';

//start while loop to go through data
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

      if($first == 1){                
        $email = $row['email'];   //set the email address
        echo $row['FName'] . ' ' . $row['LName'] . '<br />';        //output the name
        $JobId = $row['JobIid'];     //set the JobId to the current row's job id
        $first = 0;                 //change the first row so that we don't go through this initial if
} 
      else if ($row['JobId'] == $JobId) {
        $email = $row['email'];
        echo $row['FName'] . ' ' . $row['LName'] . '<br />';
} 
      else {
        //We have a new JobId, so send the email, set the JobId marker,
        // and print the applicants header again as well as the name of the next applicant from the current row
        echo 'Sending email to ' . $email . '<br /><br />';
        $JobId = $row['JobId'];
        echo 'Applicants: <br />';
        echo $row['FName'] . ' ' . $row['LName'] . '<br />';
  }
}
echo 'Sending email to ' . $email . '<br /><br />';
```

This is the best way I found to do this. Thanks for the help. If anyone sees anything glaringly incorrect with this, please let me know. :)